# Are the following two methods of accessing attributes working exactly the same?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm porting an application from VB.NET to C# and found out that I cannot use `.ItemOf` in C#, but if I do it without `.ItemOf` it seems to work. However, are the following two snippets actually doing the same thing?

**VB**

```
Public Shared Settings As NameValueCollection
'some code
 Dim key As XmlNode
 For Each key In node.ChildNodes
     MobileConfiguration.Settings.Add(key.Attributes.ItemOf("key").Value, key.Attributes.ItemOf("value").Value)
 Next
'some code
```

**C#**

```
public static NameValueCollection Settings;
//some code
 foreach (XmlNode key in node.ChildNodes)
     MobileConfiguration.Settings.Add(key.Attributes["key"].Value, key.Attributes["value"].Value);     
//some code
```

Comment: I found that `XmlNode.Attributes.ItemOf` is an indexer, hence the result for both codes seem to be same. Take a look for [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.itemof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlAttributeCollection_ItemOf_System_Int32_).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, C# indexer syntax is the equivalent of the VB code's `.ItemOf()` calls. You can see this if you look at the documentation for [`ItemOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.itemof?view=netframework-4.7.2). If your language preferences at the top are set to `C#`<sup>1</sup>, the example looks like this:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.IO;
> using System.Xml;
>
> public class Sample
> {
>   public static void Main(){
>
>     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
>     doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
>                 "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
>                 "</book>");      
>
>     //Create an attribute collection. 
>     XmlAttributeCollection attrColl = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes;
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Display all the attributes in the collection...\r\n");
>     for (int i=0; i < attrColl.Count; i++)
>     {
>       Console.Write("{0} = ", attrColl[i].Name);
>       Console.Write("{0}", attrColl[i].Value);
>       Console.WriteLine();
>     }           
>   }
> }
> ```

If your language settings are set to VB, you'll see this as the example:

> ```
> Imports System
> Imports System.IO
> Imports System.Xml
>
> public class Sample
>
>   public shared sub Main()
>
>     Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
>     doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" & _
>                 "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" & _
>                 "</book>")      
>
>     'Create an attribute collection.
>     Dim attrColl as XmlAttributeCollection = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Display all the attributes in the collection...")
>     Dim i as integer
>     for i=0  to attrColl.Count-1
>       Console.Write("{0} = ", attrColl.ItemOf(i).Name)
>       Console.Write("{0}", attrColl.ItemOf(i).Value)
>       Console.WriteLine()
>     next
>
>   end sub
> end class
> ```

C# reserves special syntax for indexers, and `ItemOf` is the indexer for the `XmlAttributeCollection` class.

---

<sup>1</sup>I know a lot of people haven't found this yet in the revamped documentation:
[image]

Comment: I had to upvote for the "If your language settings are set to VB" - I was wondering why there were no examples in any language other than C#.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - good point, it took a while for me to find it too. Added a picture footnote.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I couldn't find it, so I thoguht it's only VB samples there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like .ItemOf("key") just finds the value that corresponds with that key. In C# this is just done by placing ["key"] at the end of the object. So yes, they are doing the same thing